# How to make vault Secret ID can be reused multiple times?

Tags: go, vault

So I have a PoC Vault with `Dockerfile` something like this (full repo [here](//github.com/kokizzu/vault1)):

```
FROM hashicorp/vault

RUN apk add --no-cache bash jq

COPY reseller1-policy.hcl /vault/config/reseller1-policy.hcl
COPY terraform-policy.hcl /vault/config/terraform-policy.hcl
COPY init_vault.sh /init_vault.sh

EXPOSE 8200

ENTRYPOINT [ "/init_vault.sh" ]

HEALTHCHECK \
    --start-period=5s \
    --interval=1s \
    --timeout=1s \
    --retries=30 \
        CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "[ -f /tmp/healthy ]" ]
```

`init_vault.sh` contains:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set -e

export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'
export VAULT_FORMAT='json'

# Spawn a new process for the development Vault server and wait for it to come online
# ref: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/dev-server
vault server -dev -dev-listen-address="0.0.0.0:8200" &
sleep 5s

# authenticate container's local Vault CLI
# ref: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/login
vault login -no-print "${VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID}"

# add policy
# ref: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/policies
vault policy write terraform-policy /vault/config/terraform-policy.hcl
vault policy write reseller1-policy /vault/config/reseller1-policy.hcl

# enable AppRole auth method
# ref: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle
vault auth enable approle

# configure AppRole
# ref: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/approle#parameters
vault write auth/approle/role/dummy_role \
    token_policies=reseller1-policy \
    token_num_uses=9000 \
    secret_id_ttl="32d" \
    token_ttl="32d" \
    token_max_ttl="32d"

# overwrite our role id
vault write auth/approle/role/dummy_role/role-id role_id="${APPROLE_ROLE_ID}"

# for terraform
# ref: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/token/create
vault token create \
    -id="${TERRAFORM_TOKEN}" \
    -policy=terraform-policy \
    -ttl="32d"

# keep container alive
tail -f /dev/null & trap 'kill %1' TERM ; wait
```

with `reseller1-policy.hcl`:

```
# This section grants access for the app
path "secret/data/dummy_config_yaml/reseller1/*" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}

path "secret/dummy_config_yaml/reseller1/*" { # v1
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

and `terraform-policy.hcl`:

```
# Grant 'update' permission on the 'auth/approle/role/<role_name>/secret-id' path for generating a secret id
path "auth/approle/role/dummy_role/secret-id" {
  capabilities = ["update"]
}

path "secret/data/dummy_config_yaml/*" {
  capabilities = ["create","update","read","patch","delete"]
}

path "secret/dummy_config_yaml/*" { # v1
  capabilities = ["create","update","read","patch","delete"]
}

path "secret/metadata/dummy_config_yaml/*" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}
```

This was started with `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  testvaultserver1:
    build: ./vault-server/
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    environment:
      VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID: root
      APPROLE_ROLE_ID:         dummy_app
      TERRAFORM_TOKEN:         dummyTerraformToken
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
```

then run some script `copy_config2vault_secret2tmp.sh` on shell:

```bash
TERRAFORM_TOKEN=`cat docker-compose.yml | grep TERRAFORM_TOKEN | cut -d':' -f2 | xargs echo -n`
VAULT_ADDRESS="127.0.0.1:8200"

# retrieve secret for appsecret so dummy app can load the /tmp/secret
curl \
   --request POST \
   --header "X-Vault-Token: ${TERRAFORM_TOKEN}" \
   --header "X-Vault-Wrap-TTL: 32d" \
      "${VAULT_ADDRESS}/v1/auth/approle/role/dummy_role/secret-id" > /tmp/debug

cat /tmp/debug | jq -r '.wrap_info.token' > /tmp/secret

# check appsecret exists
cat /tmp/debug
cat /tmp/secret

VAULT_DOCKER=`docker ps| grep vault | cut -d' ' -f 1`

echo 'put secret'
cat config.yaml | docker exec -i $VAULT_DOCKER vault -v kv put -address=http://127.0.0.1:8200 -mount=secret dummy_config_yaml/reseller1/region99 raw=-

echo 'check secret length'
docker exec -i $VAULT_DOCKER vault -v kv get -address=http://127.0.0.1:8200 -mount=secret dummy_config_yaml/reseller1/region99 | wc -l
```

Then create a program to read the secret and retrieve the `config.yaml` from vault:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    vault "github.com/hashicorp/vault/api"
    "github.com/hashicorp/vault/api/auth/approle"
)

const AppRoleID = `dummy_app`

func main() {
    conf, err := TryUseVault(`http://127.0.0.1:8200`, `secret/data/dummy_config_yaml/reseller1/region99`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    log.Println(conf)
}

func TryUseVault(address, configPath string) (string, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    const secretFile = `/tmp/secret`

    config := vault.DefaultConfig() // modify for more granular configuration
    config.Address = address

    client, err := vault.NewClient(config)
    if err != nil {
        return ``, fmt.Errorf(`failed to create vault client: %w`, err)
    }

    approleSecretID := &approle.SecretID{
        FromFile: secretFile,
    }

    appRoleAuth, err := approle.NewAppRoleAuth(
        AppRoleID,
        approleSecretID,
        approle.WithWrappingToken(), // only required if the SecretID is response-wrapped
    )
    if err != nil {
        return ``, fmt.Errorf(`failed to create approle auth: %w`, err)
    }

    authInfo, err := client.Auth().Login(ctx, appRoleAuth)
    if err != nil {
        return ``, fmt.Errorf(`failed to login to vault: %w`, err)
    }

    if authInfo == nil {
        return ``, fmt.Errorf(`failed to login to vault: authInfo is nil`)
    }

    log.Println("connecting to vault: success!")

    secret, err := client.Logical().Read(configPath)
    if err != nil {
        return ``, fmt.Errorf(`failed to read secret from vault: %w`, err)
    }
    if secret == nil {
        return ``, fmt.Errorf(`failed to read secret from vault: secret is nil`)
    }
    if len(secret.Data) == 0 {
        return ``, fmt.Errorf(`failed to read secret from vault: secret.Data is empty`)
    }
    data := secret.Data[`data`]
    if data == nil {
        return ``, fmt.Errorf(`failed to read secret from vault: secret.Data.data is nil`)
    }
    m, ok := data.(map[string]interface{})
    if !ok {
        return ``, fmt.Errorf(`failed to read secret from vault: secret.Data.data is not a map[string]interface{}`)
    }
    raw, ok := m[`raw`]
    if !ok {
        return ``, fmt.Errorf(`failed to read secret from vault: secret.Data.data.raw is nil`)
    }
    rawStr, ok := raw.(string)
    if !ok {
        return ``, fmt.Errorf(`failed to read secret from vault: secret.Data.data.raw is not a string`)
    }

    // set viper from string
    return rawStr, nil
}
```

it works fine, but the problem is, the secret can only be used once

```bash
$ ./copy_config2vault_secret2tmp.sh 
{"request_id":"","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":0,"data":null,"wrap_info":{"token":"hvs.CAESIDSE_hR3-CW1CLLotQoVAhes55vI1MCDemmbWbsAvDS6Gh4KHGh2cy5QdzQ0bzlxRTJ6MUZJUFRoeGpSWFRzV0E","accessor":"7jLABMbzGVHKPCKAd7qkPx5J","ttl":2764800,"creation_time":"2023-07-18T19:34:48.619332723Z","creation_path":"auth/approle/role/dummy_role/secret-id","wrapped_accessor":"2493fc83-aaf6-7553-dd04-2ccedc39a4b1"},"warnings":null,"auth":null}
hvs.CAESIDSE_hR3-CW1CLLotQoVAhes55vI1MCDemmbWbsAvDS6Gh4KHGh2cy5QdzQ0bzlxRTJ6MUZJUFRoeGpSWFRzV0E
put secret
================== Secret Path ==================
secret/data/dummy_config_yaml/reseller1/region99

======= Metadata =======
Key                Value
---                -----
created_time       2023-07-18T19:34:48.827508755Z
custom_metadata    <nil>
deletion_time      n/a
destroyed          false
version            9
check secret length
19
```

retrieve it once works fine:

```bash
$ go run main.go
2023/07/19 02:35:52 connecting to vault: success!
2023/07/19 02:35:52 
this:
  is:
    some:
      secret: a35)*&BN)(*&%TN_@#
```

But when I run it second time, it always error (unless I run the get secret `copy_config2vault_secret2tmp.sh` script again):

```
$ go run main.go
2023/07/19 02:36:06 failed to login to vault: unable to log in to auth method: unable to unwrap response wrapping token: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/wrapping/unwrap
Code: 400. Errors:

* wrapping token is not valid or does not exist
```

Is the secret ID can only be used only once by design? or if it's not, what's the possible cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping tokens are limited to single use only. That's why it works only when You execute `copy_config2vault_secret2tmp.sh` before running Go app.

As a reference from Vault's documentation:

> When a newly created token is wrapped, Vault inserts the generated
> token into the cubbyhole of a single-use token, returning that
> single-use wrapping token. Retrieving the secret requires an unwrap
> operation against this wrapping token.

This specific part explaining use of wrapping token might help to understand the details:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/secrets-management/cubbyhole-response-wrapping#step-2-unwrap-the-secret